# WordPress on git - need help with configuration

Tags: git, amazon, cloud

I've got all my WordPress code on version control and automatically updated on the server every time I push something into an external git repo. This means that when I want to add pictures through the wordpress add media function, I can't.

I've followed the instructions from [here:](http://ulrich.pogson.ch/setup-aws-work-amazon-s3-wordpress-plugin)

However, every time I try to upload, I get this message:

> “unicorn.jpg” has failed to upload due to an error
>   Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2014/05. Is its parent directory >writable by the server?

My site is hosted on EC2 and need images on S3. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the folder/file permissions. You need to change the permsion so that the wp-content/uploads folder is writable.

This is explained in the [Amazon User Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/hosting-wordpress.html).

http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions